# Base64 encoding in PHP not working for '&' and '#'?

Tags: php, base64

My knowledge about base64 is pretty limited. I am using it as an alternative to string escaping in a content management system, for I had been warned about how weaknesses have been found in mysql_real_escape_string(); and quite sheepishly so, as I am aware of how it buffs text size up.

PHP seems to truncate everything after an instance of # or & in the string; please help me out of this one.

Also, comment on whether using base64 to maintain the 'trueness' of post content in the CMS is just plain retarded, or a wise move.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Could you perhaps include the code that you're trying to use and having issues with? -- Also, note that base64 encoding will increase text size even more than escaping would, most of the time.

Comment: It's just a simple base64_encode() call to POST from Ajax.

I think now, however, that it's being caused due to the ampersands used in crafting the POST content.

Comment: Just a heads-up re: stackoverflow etiquette: You should endeavour to accept an answer (even if it is your own) when your question's been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works:

```
$ php
<?php echo base64_decode(base64_encode("hello &# world")); ?>
hello &# world
```

you can find informations about base64 on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and in [php manual](http://us.php.net/base64_encode)

Comment: I see, damn I should have tried that out myself. So the ampersands in the AJAX query could explain the problem, but what about # ?

Comment: `#` symbols are used in URLs for the anchor portion, thus they're a reserved character just liked `&` are.

Comment: I am sure I am not seeing something here, but how would URLs creep into POSTed AJAX content?
The ampersands could probably declare new $_POST[] elements and hence truncate the rest of the string (I think). I do not see how # would do something similar?

Also, any suggestions for escaping these characters, I do not want to compromise by using a dummy text which I shall replace both ways. Is an escape character possible?

Lastly, how suitable is using Base 64.

Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, Dav was right all the way. A simple URLEncode function I grabbed off Google did the trick :)

```
return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').
                                                                replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/%20/g, '+');
```

Thanks again :)